# What is the difference between bundling feature in MVC5.0 and webpack bundling?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, webpack, bundling-and-minification

What is the difference in bundling feature between MVC5.0 and webpack bundling?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net MVC 5.0, we use [Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization/) Framework for bundling and minification.

Start from ASP.Net Core, Microsoft supports third-party frameworks for bundling and minification such as Gulp, Bower, Webpack.

*Please note that those third-party frameworks offers a lot more than just bundling and minification.*

Comment: do you have any idea how to debug those javascript which is the output of webpack in visual studio 2015?

Comment: You cannot debug easily after JavaScript files have been bundled and minified.